# Getting user data from facebook login in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I have integrated facebook login in my app.But Im unable to get user data ie it is not entering the user details loop
In Appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"email",
                            @"user_likes",
                            nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];





}


- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
                     if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");


                         [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
                          ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                            NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
                            NSError *error) {
                                  if (!error) {

                                  NSLog(@"%@",user);



                              }}];
                           break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
           [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
 if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

    }
}
```

But I dont find NSLog of user NSLog(@"%@",user) to be printed eventhough the session is opened bcoz  NSLog(@"User session found") is printed
Y is it so ?

Comment: Can you show us how you are opening the session? (Presumably something like `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:]`.

Comment: I have edited my code.Can u please have a look and rectify my mistake

Comment: How do you know the session is opened if nothing is logged?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u.Do u mean  case FBSessionStateOpen:
                     if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found"); in - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error ?

Comment: Michael Please do check my code

Comment: You say that nothing is printed with NSLog even though the session is opened. If nothing is printed, how have you determined that the session has been opened? Try setting a breakpoint or logging in `sessionStateChanged:state:error:` and see what the value of `state` is.

Comment: I mean NSLog of user details is not printed,but NSLog User session found is printed.and the state is FBSessionStateOpen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue where I was not able to enter in the block once came back after log in after an hour I figured out that I was returning mysession class instead of instance of mysession. This might fix your issue:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    return [mysession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```